# Is it okay to take the average of several normalized time series?

Tags: time-series, normalization

I have 3 time series (10 years) of economic data for 3 countries. For another analysis that I am doing, I should try and reduce these into preferably 1 time series. For this analysis I don't care so much about the absolute values, rather about the variation. 
The three time series are for the same thing, but the magnitudes vary between the countries, so obviously I need to normalize. But should I normalize all three time series and take the average, or should I take the average and normalize this?
I'm leaning towards the first option (first normalize the 3 time series and then take the average) but I am not sure this is statistically correct or okay…?